# Pagination in cakephp with find all results

Tags: mysql, cakephp, pagination

HI I want to implement pagination on my find all query results where I am getting all info related to user from different  tables

My find all query:

```
$result = $this->User->find('all',array(
                'order' => array('User.id' => 'DESC'),
                'conditions' => $filters
        ));
```

My pagination query:

```
$this->paginate['User'] = array(
            'limit' => 20,
            'order' => array('User.id' => 'DESC')
                        );
```

In query $filter my condition for result.

So I want to merge both query  & get all  user related data but only 20 user per page.

I tried but couldn't properly merge both the query.

Thanks ..

Comment: it's a long time that i've worked with the pure pagination in cake php ; i work always with datatable jquery, so i'm not sure about the syntax you use for the pagination i've some doubt plz can u take a look in this link http://technet.weblineindia.com/web/example-pagination-in-cakephp/

Comment: Thanks@maysaghira for reply but its not helping me.

Comment: see last function of http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#query-setup   you can add your conditions in pagination settings

Comment: It would be helpful to see what your `$filters` are, and the related models.

Answer (score 0):

The PaginatorComponent uses a find query that sets the limits based on request parameters, so it can do anything a regular find call can.

```
public function index() {
  // add any filters you want here
  $filters = array('RelatedModel.field' => 'value');
  $this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $filters;
  $this->Paginator->settings['contain'] = array('RelatedModel');
  $this->set('users', $this->Paginator->paginate('User'));
}
```

Here we contain RelatedModel so you can search on (assuming it's a simple join) and include RelatedModel data.